# Word filtering javascript

Tags: javascript, function

Im generally very confused by how I should go about this. (Mind you I’m very new to Javascript). I’m trying to create a word filtering function where if a word is detected its gonna print something in console. If it doesn’t then it prints that it didn’t find any bad words I’m filtering.

```
var badWords  = ["legos", "cloud", "manifold"]
var linija = 'ja volim legos'

function badWordChecker() {
if (linija = arr.filter(el => badWords.includes(el)) )

console.log('Dirty')
else{
console.log('Clean')
 }
}
```

Comment: You need to split your `linja` into individual words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split it on space and check if any of the words match:

```js
const badWords = new Set(["legos", "cloud", "manifold"]);

function hasBadWords(str) {
    if (str.split(" ").some(word => badWords.has(word))) {
        return "Dirty";
    } else {
        return "Clean";
    }
}

console.log(hasBadWords("ja volim legos")); // logs "Dirty"
console.log(hasBadWords("foo bar baz")); // logs "Clean"
```

Comment: please consider using `split(/\W+/g)` instead of using `split(" ")`

Comment: Sorry, Can you explain to me how '.some(word => badWords.has(word)))' works? I'm having trouble understanding and implementing the code.

Comment: `.some` takes in a function and returns `true` if there's at least one element in the array that matches that function. `badWords` is a set, so `.has(word)` checks if the word is in the bad words set. Basically, it reads like english: if there is some word that the set of bad words has, then it's dirty.

Comment: Yeah but my problem is once I throw the code you sent in VSC, I get a badWords.has is not a function? Thats kinda my problem, I've tried looking up .includes because I thought you ment that rather than .has?

Comment: Note the `new Set()` around the array. If you don't do that, you'd have to use `.includes`, which is an array method, but much slower than the set method.

Comment: Thanks man! I obv messed something up while looking at your code lol, thank you very much!